# Display HTML Table in webview

Tags: android, android-widget, android-webview

How to display HTML  table with rows and columns in WebView in Android.

Give me some example.

Answer (score 7):

Create an `HTML` template

```
    String myTable = "<table border=1>" +
        "<tr>" +
        "<td>row 1, cell 1</td>" +
        "<td>row 1, cell 2</td>" +
        "</tr>" +
        "<tr>" +
        "<td>row 2, cell 1</td>" +
        "<td>row 2, cell 2</td>" +
        "</tr>" +
        "</table>";
```

and load into your `WebView`

```
myWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, myTable, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

Comment: It works fine, but the problem is I am unable to use other features of HTML table like I want to reduce the cellspacing between rows, or I want to add some color to cell spacing called Border Color, which I am not able to do with Android. Can u give me sample code for table which appears exactly like table with lines in middle of columns and rows.
Thanks in Advance,

Comment: In landscape mode the text disappears. if size is bigger. Not able to put scroll within webview. Any idea how to implement scroll in webview

Comment: I wrote: myWebView.loadData(myTable, "text/html", "utf-8");  and the page wasn't loaded. I replaced it to myWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, myTable, "text/html", "utf-8", null);  as mentioned, and the page was loaded!

Answer (score 2):

Its also working for me:

```
String tag = "<table border=1>" +
                "<tr>" +
                   "<td>row 1, cell 1</td>" +
                   "<td>row 1, cell 2</td>" +
                "</tr>" +
                "<tr>" +
                   "<td>row 2, cell 1</td>" +
                   "<td>row 2, cell 2</td>" +
                "</tr>" +
             "</table>";

((WebView) findViewById(R.id.web)).loadData(tag, "text/html", "utf-8");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is an issue related to Android web view's in 2.2 and 2.3. The table tags like width, cell-spacing, and cell-padding are not supported in some web views and thus should not be used. If you want to style a table with webView.loadData(), use inline stlying with the style tag only.

Table border should also be removed as well.