# How to create table/data grid for mobile devices using HTML/CSS/JavaScript

Tags: iphone, android, mobile, jqtouch

I want to show a table/data grid as shown below, this is for mobile devices like iPhone and Andriod phones. Are there any examples for this? (using plain HTML/CSS/JavaScript)

[image]

Comment: Accept an answer if it resolved your question. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you have the HTML, CSS, etc. ready and working, you can use UIWebView class on iOS/iPhone to view your HTML file.

```
NSString *htmlString = @"<html>.......</html>";
NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@""];

[myWebView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:baseURL];
```

Answer (score 0):

Basic example: [Display HTML Table in webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3525649/how-to-display-table-using-html-in-webview-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

I had to do something like this when developing using jQTouch. I simply created an Edge-to-edge list with one item, and place a table inside it:

```
<ul class="edgetoedge">
    <li>
        <table sytle="width:100%; text-align: center; padding: 5px">
            <tr><td>Row 1-1</td><td>Row 1-2</td><td>Row 1-3</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Row 2-1</td><td>Row 2-2</td><td>Row 2-3</td></tr>
        </table>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Then style the table (i.e. `<table>`, `<tr>`, and `<td>`) to your heart's content.