# How to sent table form on email body in android programmatically

Tags: android, html

I want to send table form in email body. But I have searched and got that html table tag is not supported on android. Please give me suggestion so that I have sent email with table form in android.

Answer (score 0):

Check this question ..[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12154790/android-how-to-format-the-text-as-table-in-email-body-of-email-client)

It seems there is no way to do it other than sending the html as an attachment.