# How to send Html Table in Email in android Application

Tags: android, email, html-email

I am sending An email through Gmail. I have data in rows and Collunms . I want to send HTML table in Email throught Gmail.

```
                mailBody+="\n<!DOCTYPE html> \n<html>\n<body>\n<table border="+1+" style="+"width:300px"+">\n<tr>\n<td>arslan</td>\n<td>arslan</td>\n<td>asad</td>\n<td>50</td>\n</tr>\n</table>\n</body>\n</html>";
```

I have send mailbody in email but it didn't work. I need that receiver should get Table in Email.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code :

```
final Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.parse("mailto:"));
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "The Subject");
shareIntent.putExtra(
Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
Html.fromHtml(new StringBuilder()
    .append("<p><b>Some Content</b></p>")
    .append("<small><p>More content</p></small>")
    .toString())
);
```

For more Links see

[android - How to format the text as table in email body of email client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12154790/android-how-to-format-the-text-as-table-in-email-body-of-email-client)

[How to send HTML email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2007540/how-to-send-html-email)

Also do check if this works on Android 4.0 and  up.