# Posting HTML Content - Table in Android Email BOdy

Tags: android, html, android-intent, html-email

I want to show TABULAR Data in an Android GMAIL Body from my app, pre-filled. There are many similar topics available on Stackoverflow, but no one has provided a good solution to my particular problem.

Here is what I am doing,

```
final Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.parse("mailto:"));
                shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "The Subject");
                shareIntent.putExtra(
                Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
                Html.fromHtml("<!DOCTYPE html><html><body><table><tr><th>head 1</th><th>head 2</th><th>head 3</th></tr><tr><td>data 1</td><td>data 2</td><td>data 3</td></tr></table></body></html>"));
                mContext.startActivity(shareIntent);
```

Can anyone please check this, and let me know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: i think you should add settype..

Comment: Where I have to add this?

Comment: after intent initialization..are you getting any error?can you show UI design also..

Answer (score -2):

Try below code :

```
final Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.parse("mailto:"));
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "The Subject");
shareIntent.putExtra(
Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
Html.fromHtml(new StringBuilder()
    .append("<p><b>Some Content</b></p>")
    .append("<small><p>More content</p></small>")
    .toString())
);
```

For more Links see

[android - How to format the text as table in email body of email client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12154790/android-how-to-format-the-text-as-table-in-email-body-of-email-client)

[How to send HTML email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2007540/how-to-send-html-email)

Also do check if this works on Android 4.0 and  up.